# How can I sum up columns in a Matrix or Dataframe?

Tags: r, matrix, tibble

I want to to sum up columns 3-7 of my Matrix(1-7). But in column 1 are words (so "character").

So if I use the `rowSums` function I get an `Error "x must be numeric"` (also when I apply the as_tibble function). When I apply the normal tibble() function on my Matrix I get another error that my data only has one column so I don't know how to "aim" for a specific column.
Hope I could explain it good enough, thanks in advance

Comment: `rowSums(apply(matrix[,3:7], 2, as.numeric))`, first change to numeric, then get the sum of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can select only numeric columns:

```
rowSums(your_matrix[,c(3:7)])
```

or using a logical vector:

```
rowSums(your_matrix[, sapply(your_matrix, is.numeric)])
```

Comment: But the first doesn't work b/c its not numeric. And the second one I tried and received 0 as rowsum.

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example for better understanding of your problem